# I cannot rotate of move camera anymore for some reason

Tags: camera

I was working on making a mesh, i left the window open and someone got on the computer after me, im not sure what they clicked but i can no longer rotate camera, everytime i try it moves the object instead, if i try to deselect the object, it does nothing. Here's a picture
[image]

Im probably just an idiot who hasnt realized anything, if you need more information i'll try my best but im still new and can't figure out why i can't anymore. I have tried ctrl+c but all it did was zoom out. I know the mesh looks bad but, well i had just stared. I even tied installing and uninstalling blender

Comment: I'm sure with the [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) somebody could find your problem in about a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell blender what object to use as a Camera

[image]

Comment: Lol im a idiot, my mouse was the problem. My middle mouse button wasnt working on that mouse anymore for some reason. I bought a new one and it works. Sorry for the trouble.